# My father is a French Citizen. Can I get French citizenship through him?

Tags: citizenship, eu-citizens

I was wondering if its possible for me to get French citizenship through my father. Most of his family lives in France and so would sometimes come to visit us.

I have read so many answers on this situation. However, I just want a conclusive response. Or information from anyone who has had experience with this. I want to hopefully in the future visit my cousins.

I am currently looking into seeing if it's possible to obtain French Citizenship.

Comment: Question should include: "Have I always been a French citizen from birth?"

Comment: I wonder if the nationality of the OP also counts?

Comment: @JanDoggen Not in terms of asserting the OP's French citizenship.  There *may* be an issue that the OP's current nationality requires adults to choose between multiple nationalities acquired at birth - but that would really be a separate question.

Comment: I agree that this is a duplicate.  (The linked question has an additional complication, but the answers work even if the French parent is still alive.)

Comment: By default, you should already be French. There are complications if your French parent has lived abroad for a long time and never used his French citizenship (many of which have been discussed here before) but we would need more details to see how they apply to you (in particular where you and your father reside and for how long).

Comment: "I want to hopefully in the future visit my cousins": it is not necessary to be a French citizen to visit people in France.